# input checkbox check out of position

Tags: html, css

I created a custom checkbox using css3 and it turned out looking like this with the check slightly lower than where it should be...

[image]

Here is the html code applicable to this checkbox:

```
<div>
    <input id='remember_me' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='remember_me'>Remember me</label>
</div>
```

Here is the css code applicable to this checkbox:

```
input[type='checkbox'] + label:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    float: left;  
    width: 12px;  
    height: 12px;  
    margin-right: 4px;

    border: 1px solid white;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:before {
    content:'✓';
    color: white;
}
input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}
div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Is there any way to move the check to the centre of the box?

Comment: Hello, http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/wv8ksqgL/ IS IT YOUR CODE?

Comment: lol 1 sec I guess I should add the container too with the flexbox stuff ^__^

Comment: [No change](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/wv8ksqgL/1/) I don't see any label css in your code. post proper code.

Comment: Please provide demo.

Comment: You have to change it to a color that isn't white. However, @Derek, please provide a fiddle that shows your problem, as after I changed the color to black, everything looked aligned.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wv8ksqgL/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/wv8ksqgL/3/

set `line-height`

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:before {
    content:'✓';
    color: blue;
    line-height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: @ Vitorino Fernandes ,if you remove line-height also, it looks aligned??http://jsfiddle.net/wv8ksqgL/5/

Comment: it is slightly at the bottom @ManjunathSiddappa

Comment: on mine it didn't.. it was my lack of providing a proper demo but give this one a try if you are interested: jsfiddle.net/wv8ksqgL/4

Comment: no, it is not?? just you need to change the color??@ Vitorino Fernandes